# SpringBoot and H2 autogenerated field

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a field on a POJO

```
@Id
@Column(name="TAG_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer tagId;
```

When I start up the service with H2 as the database I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TAG (TAG_ID NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED AS[*] IDENTITY, etc... PRIMARY KEY (TAG_ID)) "; expected "ALWAYS, BY"; SQL statement:
create table tag (tag_id number(10,0) generated as identity, etc... primary key (tag_id)) [42001-197]
```

What is this `expected "ALWAYS, BY"` error about? Why can't it generate the table?

Comment: Check the dialect in the persistence.xml. For H2 it should be `create table Tag (TAG_ID integer generated by default as identity, primary key (TAG_ID))`

Comment: What’s persistence.xml? This doesn’t exist.

Comment: Oh right, spring-boot. Check application.properties or add one. Whatever dialect you have set is trying to create an integer with number(10,0) which isn't correct for H2.

Comment: Adding `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` seems to fix it. Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelB You should add an answer and mark it accepted. I came here and almost missed the solution since it is sitting in the comments. worked for me too, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` . Maybe H2 don't support identity mechanism.

Comment: AUTO simply tells the JPA provider to do what it wants. H2 clearly supports IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

Code in POJO (entity class) is fine, no need to do any changes. Need to supply `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` parameter from either `bootstrap.yml` file or from `application.yml` file (when `bootstrap.yml` not considered) under `src/test/resources`.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```